# Fourier Transform, Which steps are wrong?

Tags: fourier-transform

I am trying to calculate one FT problem, but when I finished this in my way, and then looked the answer, I found I probably derive an incorrect answer. However, I can not figure out which steps are wrong. Any suggestions are appreciated

$$x(t) = e^{j3t}e^{-|5t+7|}$$

My method:

1.Rewrite $$x(t)$$ as
$$x(t) = e^{-7}e^{j3t}e^{-5t}u(t) + e^{7}e^{5t}u(-t)e^{j3t}$$
where u(t) is unit step function

2.Define helper functions
$$v_1(t) = e^{-5t}u(t) \to V_1(w) = \frac{1}{5+jw}$$
$$v_2(t) = v_1(-t) \to V_2(w) = \frac{1}{5-jw}$$
$$v_3(t) = e^{j3t}v_1(t) \to V_3(w) = \frac{1}{5+j(w-3)}$$
$$v_4(t) = e^{j3t}v_2(t) \to V_4(w) = \frac{1}{5-j(w-3)}$$

3.Combine above functions together
$$X(w) = \frac{e^{-7}}{5+j(w-3)} + \frac{e^{7}}{5-j(w-3)}$$

The correct answer is:
$$X(w) = \frac{10e^{\frac{j7(w-3)}{5}}}{(w-3)^{2}+25}$$

Comment: It seems you are on the right track. Now combine the two fractions by multiplying them by the denominator of the other one. That way you'll have just one fraction that is gonna look really similar to the final answer.

Comment: @ebabio I tried, but the numerator cannot become the final answer.

Comment: My bad, I didn't check thoroughly. The answer should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is right at the start: your rewritten expression for $x(t)$ is wrong.

We have $5t+7$ changes sign when $t=-7/5$, not when $t=0$. So your step functions need to be shifted.